# Xdebug - PhpStorm breaks on other process, but not the original run configuration

Tags: phpstorm, xdebug, run-configuration

I've had Xdebug set up and working properly in the past, but seem to have a real problem getting it to work consistently. This is a WordPress/WooCommerce install and I'm simply trying to load the homepage with some search query parameters so that I can debug a custom function.

Currently, I can't get it to break properly when I debug using a run configuration. It just won't break at all unless I tick the button to listen for incoming connections. At that point, I have to wade through every single index.php and cron.php process that runs, waiting for the right one to come along.

I'm not crazy, am I? I should be able to look at the single debug process and not all these others? It's as if PhpStorm is not receiving the initial connection when I run the configuration.

[image]

Comment: Can you shar emore details? If you haven't checked the box to listen for incoming connections, why should PhpStorm do that instead?

Comment: Also, have you checked "Break at first line" at any chance? That could explain why each and every request is caught

Comment: @NicoHaase Previously I could leave that box unchecked and it would only debug the initial process that opened (ex: "wp-dev homepage" visible above). And to answer your other question, I have both enabled and disabled the "break at first line". It still only breaks on the other processes, not the original one. Such a strange thing.